# getting error with django slugify

Tags: python, django, slug

I am trying this

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

In [8]: mystr = "This is john"

In [9]: slugify(mystr)
```

and i am getting this error

`TypeError: must be unicode, not str`

if i use this

`from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify` then it works but it does not chnage `underscores` to `hyphens` and if i have `dots` it simple removes it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `slugify()` expects a [unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) object.

The easiest way to solve it is passing the string as a unicode object

```
mystr = u'This is John'
```

or

```
mystr = unicode('This is John')
>> u'This is John'
```

Comment: For future searchers... this answer is only relevant in Python 2. There is no unicode() in Python 3 and all strings are Unicode in Python 3.